# i can pushViewController(UIViewController(), animated: true) ins side collection view cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I build `collectionView` inside other `collectionViewCell` , but I can't make

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(UIViewController(), animated: true)
```

what should I do ?

Comment: iam sory i can't do this

Comment: from where you want to push the VC.

Comment: context is not clear please elaborate your problem and provide some code sample?

Comment: ok iam inside UICollectionViewCell class ,  i make button and iam trying to add target for it

Comment: button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toUserProfile), for: .touchDown)

Comment: @objc func toUserProfile()  {
        
        let controller = UserProfileViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        // loadingProgress.show(view: self.view)
        controller.user_id = "1"
        UINavigationController().pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to instantiate your viewController before push.

First of all you have to be sure if you have a `navigationController`, then to instatiate your `viewController`

**See an example**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as UIViewController
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: it is not work inside it , also iam not using storyboard iam coding just

Answer (score 0):

import UIKit
class ItemDetailsHeaderCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
let upperTab: UIView = {
   let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = .white
    return v
}()

let profileImage : UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user")
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    image.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return image
}()

let usernameLbl : UIButton = {
    let lbl = UIButton()
    lbl.setTitle("Ali Abdalla Mansour", for: [])
    lbl.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
   // lbl.textColor = main_color
    lbl.setTitleColor(main_color, for: [])
    lbl.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .left
    return lbl
}()



let optionsMenu : UIImageView = {
    let img = UIImageView()
    img.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "comments")
    return img
}()

let seprator : UIView = {
    let lbl = UIView()
    lbl.backgroundColor = .gray
    return lbl
}()


let adImage : UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "keyboard")
    image.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

//        image.layer.cornerRadius = 20
//        image.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return image
    }()

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()

}


func setupViews()  {

        setupUpperTab()
        addSubview(upperTab)
        addSubview(adImage)
        upperTab.anchor(topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 50)
        adImage.anchor(upperTab.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 270)



}


func setupUpperTab()  {

        upperTab.addSubview(profileImage)
        upperTab.addSubview(usernameLbl)
        upperTab.addSubview(optionsMenu)
        upperTab.addSubview(seprator)
        profileImage.anchor(upperTab.topAnchor, left: upperTab.leftAnchor, bottom: upperTab.bottomAnchor, right:usernameLbl.leftAnchor, topConstant: 5 , leftConstant: 12, bottomConstant: 5, rightConstant: 8, widthConstant: 40, heightConstant: 40)
        usernameLbl.anchor(upperTab.topAnchor, left: profileImage.rightAnchor , bottom: upperTab.bottomAnchor, right: optionsMenu.leftAnchor, topConstant: 15, leftConstant: 8, bottomConstant: 15, rightConstant: 8, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0  )
        optionsMenu.anchor(upperTab.topAnchor, left: usernameLbl.rightAnchor, bottom: upperTab.bottomAnchor, right: upperTab.rightAnchor, topConstant: 15, leftConstant: 8, bottomConstant: 15, rightConstant: 12, widthConstant: 20, heightConstant: 20)


        seprator.anchor(nil, left: upperTab.leftAnchor, bottom: upperTab.bottomAnchor, right: upperTab.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 1)





        usernameLbl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toUserProfile), for: .touchDown)

}




@objc func toUserProfile()  {

    let controller = UserProfileViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    // loadingProgress.show(view: self.view)
    controller.user_id = "1"
    UINavigationController().pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

}



required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Comment: iam trying to apply the code inside toUserProfile Function